# update a table after update in mssql triggers

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I have two tables: productType and product table. both tables have an attribute 'status'. What I want to happen is that whenever I update the productType status, product's status will also be updated. I want to use trigger for that but I don't know the right syntax. I am using sql server management studio 2012. Thanks :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic syntax.

Comment: LMGTFY http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Answer (score 0):

With a bit more info in the question I could give a better answer, but this should get you started:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg1 
ON producttype 
after UPDATE 
AS 
    UPDATE product 
    SET    status = inserted.status 
    WHERE  rowid = inserted.rowid
```

Good luck!

Comment: You might want to include a where clause or a join. The way you have this coded it will update the entire product table.